# When I bench press, why do my hips sometimes cramp up?

Tags: form, bench-press

When I bench press, I sometimes feel a muscle seize up slightly [distal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location#Proximal_and_distal) and [lateral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_anatomical_terms#Near_or_away_from_the_vertical_longitudinal_center_of_the_body) from my [ASIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anterior_superior_iliac_spine). I don't know what muscle this is, but I'm guessing it's involved with external rotation or abduction. This happens sometimes in the left hip, sometimes the right hip, sometimes both simultaneously.

It happens when I'm arching my back hard, with glutes pressed against the bench, legs open at about a 30° angle and feet flat against the ground.

I find it hard to maintain the arch of my back off the bench without these muscles occasionally seizing.

Am I tensing up an area that I should be leaving relaxed? Is this a sign of improper form?

Comment: Based on comments and googling it arching or no arching in a controversial topic, and can cause back issues, try to do some workouts without the back arch and see if it keep cramping

Answer (score 1):

The bench does require significant hip/leg drive, there are even stories of powerlifters tearing hammies or quads while benching. Pretty much everything needs to be tight on a max bench attempt, so I don't really think there are "right" muscles to keep relaxed. I would just chalk it up as the nature of the beast, assuming the seizing/cramping is just causing discomfort and not resulting in injury.

Comment: This is re-assuring. It is just very distracting, and happens at the heavy weights where I need the most focus. It doesn't feel like an injury, and isn't affecting deadlifts or squats.

Comment: @Kate - FWIW, I get the same thing in my arches (cramping under load) when I return to swimming after a layoff. Increased fitness and stretching the flexors and extensors for the foot usually alleviates it.

Comment: John! I don't know where you get "stretching the flexors and extensors for the foot usually alleviates it."  I mean, is this like a scientific research proven method for all symptoms like Kate presented?  If you want to know the truth about reducing the TFL cramping during hyperextension of the lumber, then I will share without "foot placement" on the bench.  One is to stretch the TFL during breaks.  Two is to get a PT to give you some lumbar spine mobility exercises.  Since lumbar spine stiffness can put more stress on the hips and vice versa.  We called this "Regional Interdependence."

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change our feet position, and see if that changes the situation.
I found that if I slightly turn my heels a little outward and don´t spread my legs to wide, I have less strain in the hip region but enough stability to get a nice leg drive during the lift. Also, you have to really avoid raising your hips off the bench ... during the push movement.

Answer (score -1):

Kate,

This muscle that you are feeling tensing up could very well be the [Tensor Fasciae Latae (TFL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_fasciae_latae_muscle).  This muscle is activate by externally rotate the hip, slightly abduct the hip and slightly flex the hip (30 degrees in both motions).

Don't forget that this muscle is also a part of our ITB, so when you externally rotate your tibia, it will also engage at the hip.  This muscle is activated the most during a hyperextended of the lumbar spine in addition to the motions described above (ER and ABD or the hip).  People with increased lordosis or arching the back during benching will sometimes feel like this muscle is cramping.

You seem knowledgable about weight training.  So, I would like to ask you why are you allowing your back to arch that much during bench pressing?  Although this is a very common mistake many people do at the gym, and although they claim that they can bench more (cheating).  However, this very technique (arching the back) has been shown to increase more stress on both the hips (in your case) and in the lower back area.

Have you tried placing your feet on the bench (with bent-knees)?

Comment: -1 for recommending an unsafe alternative (feet on bench). It is less stable, not recommended and does not address the problem (usually flexibility), it just avoids it.

Comment: @JohnP why it is unsafe and not recommended? I see that it is not so stable, and demands some balance, but I think it can help with avoid back arching

Comment: I'm using the back arch because it believed it to be standard powerlifting form. I'm trying to do exactly what Mark Rippetoe directs us to do in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBNeeeTId1M

Comment: JohnP!  Thanks for your input, however, according to Kate, "It happens when I'm arching my back hard, with glutes pressed against the bench, legs open at about a 30° angle and feet flat against the ground."  First of all, how are you going to stretch a "bad habit."  To fix problems, you have to fix problems, not symptoms.  Secondly, is there a scientific research saying that feet placement on the bench is unsafe during bench pressing?

Comment: Feet on the bench is not allowed during competition, so I'm not going to switch to that. If my issue may be related to IT band tightness, I could stretch that. Even if it's not that, I won't make anything worse. I will post a form video soon to get a better check that I'm not doing something wrong form-wise.

Comment: Kate!  I use to work with the powerlifting team from Louisiana Tech University as a graduate assistant.  Just to let you know some information, Louisiana Tech Powerlifting Team has won numerous national championships.  I agree with you and understand that this is a pretty standard form when it comes to bench pressing for powerlifting, and this is because you are actually able to lift more by aching your back (using your lumbar spine to extend your your upper body during a concentric phase of the bench press).

Comment: Kate!  Thanks for making it more clear regarding your goal is to continue to keep this form as this is required for your powerlifting standardization technique.  Don't change that because it's against the rule.  However, you cannot really stretch your ITB because it will take you years to get this flexibility going.  You should stretch your TFL (as above) instead (http://ptclinic.com/medlibrary/pdf/758.pdf)

Comment: @GetFitChimp - http://www.researchgate.net/publication/8390730_Maintenance_of_EMG_activity_and_loss_of_force_output_with_instability/file/3bb5f8e9e4f51b2d6d1940049dafebf6.pdf or http://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/Abstract/2008/09000/Muscular_Outputs_During_Dynamic_Bench_Press_Under.26.aspx or http://gsareach.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/JSCR-07-Bench.pdf All of these suggest that there is more neuromuscular activity as stabilizes are activated, but that the actual performance of the bench press itself drops anywhere from 6-50% depending on the type of instability.

Comment: @GetFitChimp - Also, your assertion that it will take "years" to get ITB flexibility going is just flat wrong.

Comment: John!  We are not talking about the activation with feet up in the air or on the bench here, also we are not talking about the feet placement need to be on the ground for the bench press.  We are talking about the proper way to decrease lumbar hyperextension during bench pressing.  So, I don't know where you are going with your activation and feet placement.  Also, show me a study proving that you can get gain ITB flexibility.  Thanks for a great conversation so far.

Comment: @GetFitChimp - The last line of your recommendation is "Have you tried placing your feet on the bench (with bent-knees)?" I downvoted your answer for an unsafe recommendation, and provided research to show why it's not recommended. If you wish, I can also find statistics on accident rates/improper benching, but that would be spoon feeding. And here is one (of many many) study on ITB flexibility - http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=YlKY6aLJMB8C&oi=fnd&pg=PA116&dq=increasing+ITB+flexibility&ots=6kN_Q8cSSh&sig=U0jThj3W3E9VvZ1igNkgjIjhnGo#v=onepage&q=increasing%20ITB%20flexibility&f=false

Comment: John! I'm not here to get votes.  I'm here to learn and share fitness and medical knowledge.  First of all, I'm not telling anyone to place their feet on the bench for muscle activation.  You are! I'm telling everyone to do so to reduce lumbar hyperextension.  Secondly, the study you presented had poor quality (number of subjects, not randomized controlled study, no repeated measures, results are wide with 6-50% in addition to not even comparing the same thing). This study compared it with a swiss ball, not a bench, which is totally different when it comes to stability surfaces.

Comment: John! Secondly, ITB flexibility is an old term that us PTs are trying to get away.  The truth is that you can't really stretch a tendon.  You can however, stretch the muscle and its belly.  Think about it, if you can stretch a tendon, then why on earth would the orthopedists replace your ACL with a tendon???  By the way, I treat patients with shoulder and lower back pain all the time due to poor bench pressing technique.  One is arching their backs, and two is lifting too much weights in poor form and technique.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7897/discussion-between-johnp-and-getfitchimp)

Comment: @GetFitChimp, care to expand upon why you are trying to get Kate to eliminate her back arch? IMO(as well as almost every power lifter), you want to arch as much as possible during a bench. More arch -> shorter ROM -> more pounds on your press.

Comment: @GetFitChimp Thank you for helping identify this as the TFL/ITB.